# Pegar texto do span de um site e retornar no console

Tags: java

Como posso pegar uma span de um site e retornar no console o texto?
Tentei desta forma, mas não sei como pegar o Span:

```
public void SpanSite(){
   URL url = new URL("https://google.com.br");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
}
```

Aceito outros metódos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) para isso. Exemplo: para pegar todos os *spans* do [google](https://www.google.com.br/), você poderia fazer desta forma:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.br").get();
doc.select("span")
    .stream()
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.text()));
```

**Edit**:

Para procurar um elemento que contém um determinado texto, você pode usar os *Pseudo selectors* `:containsOwn(textoASerBuscado)` ou `:matchesOwn(regex)`. Exemplo:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.br").get();
doc.select("span:containsOwn(google)")   //Busca todos os spans que contenham "google"
    .stream()
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.text()));
```

Para saber sobre outros seletores, você pode olhar na [documentação da classe Selector](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Ok, como posso fazer uma verificação se contém tal span com tal texto no site? Por exemplo: if(s.contains("Exemplo")

Comment: @BetaDarkNight Editei e adicionei um exemplo na resposta para esse caso.